# Output user content to JavaScript variable (avoid XSS)

Tags: javascript, php, xss

I need to do the following:

```
<?php
$userContentFromDatabase = 'Some string that may contain "double  quotes" ';
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
var userContent = "<?=  $userContentFromDatabase ?>";
</script>
```

How can I avoid the double quotes from interfering with the JavaScript code?

Answer (score 2):

Use `json_encode()` on the PHP side and return an object as this will take care of all of the slashes and what not that might break your code.

Or just add slashes using `str_replace()` if you think that the only problem area will be the double quotes.

Comment: Escaping double quotes is not enough. As an example </script> will end the script tag, and break out. 
If the content contains </script><img src=x onerror=alert(1)> you will see a popup.

Answer (score -1):

You need more escaping than that if you want to safely output user data in a javascript variable. See rule 3 https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#RULE_.233_-_JavaScript_Escape_Before_Inserting_Untrusted_Data_into_JavaScript_Data_Values